# Converting a datetime object to an integer python

Tags: python, datetime, int

I would like to convert a datetime object to an int in python:

```
import datetime

time_entered = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input("Time1: "), "%H%M")
time_left = datetime.datetime.strptime(raw_input("Time2"), "%H%M")

time_taken = time_left - time_entered

int(time_taken)
```

When I run that code I get the following error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not
>   'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: When you subtract 2 datetimes you get a timedelta object from this: `time_left - time_entered`

Comment: what do want to do with the int value?

Comment: And what units do you want that `int` to be? seconds? microseconds? days, minutes, hours, ...?

Comment: I want to work out the speed of a vehicle over a certain distance. Minutes ... I think.

Answer (score 22):

You can convert the datetime object to a timetuple, and then use the time.mktime function

```python
import time
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = int(time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()))
```

Convert it back with:

```html
now = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
```

Comment: I think it's more intuitively appropriate to do `int(datetime.now().timestamp())`. Note that sub second accuracy is lost in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Converting a timedelta to an float/int in minutes can be done by:

```
time_taken.total_seconds()*60
```