# Python, convert timestamp string to MMDDHH integer

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, datetime

I have a timestamp string such as:

`2019-01-04 21:15:00`

I would like to convert this to an integer with the form MMDDHH, rounded to the nearest hour. In this case the result would be:

`10421`

Python datetime solution preferred, but Pandas works too.

Comment: You need round to neatest hour don't you ?

Comment: Yes.... looks like accepted answer was modified. Retaining accepted answer for the use of datetime over Pandas, and conversion to integer.

Comment: If you prefer python , you can remove the pandas tag next time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html) library:

```
import datetime as dt

# Read your string into a datetime object
>>> date_string = dt.datetime.strptime('2019-01-04 21:15:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>> print date_string
2019-01-04 21:15:00

# Convert it to a different format string
>>> different_date_string = dt.datetime.strftime(date_string, '%m%d%H')
>>> print different_date_string
010421

# Convert it to an integer
>>> print int(different_date_string)
10421
```

For a solution with rounding, try this function:

```
>>> def datestr2int(datestring):
...   d = dt.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
...   if d.minute >= 30:
...     d = d + dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
...   else:
...     pass
...   s = dt.datetime.strftime(d, '%m%d%H')
...   return int(s)
... 
>>> datestr2int('2019-01-04 21:15:00')
10421
>>> datestr2int('2019-01-04 21:30:00')
10422
>>> datestr2int('2019-01-04 23:35:00')
10500
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing with `round` + `strftime`

```
pd.to_datetime(s).dt.round('H').dt.strftime('%m%d%H')
Out[249]: 
0    010421
1    010421
2    010421
dtype: object
```

---

Data input

```
s=pd.Series(['2019-01-04 21:15:00','2019-01-04 21:15:00','2019-01-04 21:15:00'])
```

Comment: So clean, this should be the answer imo.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this has an answer on StackOverflow already..

[Converting a datetime object to an integer python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29238540/converting-a-datetime-object-to-an-integer-python)

I tried it and it works for me.

Comment: This is not the same question. There is some conversion also, yes, but the rounding in this question makes your linked discussion not sufficient for a full answer.